# How do I make a contract object model equivalent to what I need the response XML to look like in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, api, datacontract

I feel I have done this many times, but it seems like I have to jump through too many hoops, and I am wondering if there is an easier way.

I am using WCF to build out an API (REST and SOAP endpoints). I am building out what I would like the XML response to look like from one of my calls, and I would like to know the easiest way to get its equivalent object model (Data Contracts).

here is a sample XML request where GetSectionInvitesResponse is the top level contract that should be returned from the API call.

```
<GetSectionInvitesResponse>
 <UserID></UserID>
     <OrganizationInvites>
            <SectionInvites>
        <SectionSubscriber>
            <Section>
                <ID></ID>
                <Name></Name>
                <Description></Description>
                <Descriptor></Descriptor>
                <ParentID></ParentID>
            </Section>
            <SectionSubscriberID>
        </SectionSubscriber>
        <SectionSubscriber>
            <Section>
                <ID></ID>
                <Name></Name>
                <Description></Description>
                <Descriptor></Descriptor>
                <ParentID></ParentID>
            </Section>
            <SectionSubscriberID>
        </SectionSubscriber>
    </SectionInvites>
 </OrganizationInvites>
 <OrganizationInvites>
            <SectionInvites>
        <SectionSubscriber>
            <Section>
                <ID></ID>
                <Name></Name>
                <Description></Description>
                <Descriptor></Descriptor>
                <ParentID></ParentID>
            </Section>
            <SectionSubscriberID>
        </SectionSubscriber>
        <SectionSubscriber>
            <Section>
                <ID></ID>
                <Name></Name>
                <Description></Description>
                <Descriptor></Descriptor>
                <ParentID></ParentID>
            </Section>
            <SectionSubscriberID>
        </SectionSubscriber>
        <SectionSubscriber>
            <Section>
                <ID></ID>
                <Name></Name>
                <Description></Description>
                <Descriptor></Descriptor>
                <ParentID></ParentID>
            </Section>
            <SectionSubscriberID>
        </SectionSubscriber>
    </SectionInvites>
 </OrganizationInvites>
</GetSectionInvitesResponse>
```

**EDIT**
Because I was not clear enough in my initial post, I want to make more clear what I am aiming to gain from this question.

I want to know the best way to expose this over SOAP and REST with minimal duplicated code while following the same XML schema as shown above?

Comment: Ah, @JohnSaunders, your comments always bring a smile... for what it's worth, Mr. CSAlum, he's right: the fastest way you'll come to your solution in this situation is start with a basic model and see what comes out. Tweak, iterate, retry.

Comment: @JerKimball: I'd have started coding for him, but was still at my day job.

Comment: @JohnSaunders What else are we supposed to do while the solution builds? :)

Comment: I guess I did not expose the question specific enough. What I was trying to get at was more along the lines of, What is the most efficient way to expose this object model over both REST and SOAP where they follow the same XML schema as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can:

1. Paste the sample xml into your favorte xml editor
2. Have the editor auto generate an xml schema for you. In Visual Studio its XML->Generate Schema. For example `InvitesResponse.xsd`.
3. From a command prompt run `svcutil /dconly InvitesResponse.xsd /language:C#` to create a DataContract file.

Out of curiosity I went through these steps and discovered:

1. `<SectionSubscriberID>` isn't closed correctly in your xml.
2. That the DataContractSerializer doesn't allow node sequences the way you currently have them defined.

svcutil output:

> Error: Type 'GetSectionInvitesResponse' in namespace '' cannot be
>   imported. 'maxOccurs' on element 'OrganizationInvites' must be 1.
>   Either c hange the schema so that the types can map to data contract
>   types or use ImportXmlType or use a different serializer.

So I found the [DataContract Schema Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112.aspx) that points out that  in a complex type must have maxOccurs = 1.

You will probably have to change your schema if you want to keep the DataContract serializer and not switch to the XmlSerializer... which you would also discover if you just started coding.

It is at this point that the wisdom of @John Sanders kicked in and I stopped.